# Is it possible to restore wiki of tag aliased to another tag?

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process, tag-wiki

According to some rumour and information on [cron info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) there used to be a [crontab wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) about cron troubleshooting. However, at January 16, according to the comment under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44415191/script-cant-find-library-when-run-as-cron-job-works-fine-when-run-manually) the [crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crontab) tag has been aliased to [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron). Apparently, the original [crontab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/crontab) wiki is not accessible anymore. Is it possible to restore it as a part of [cron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron) wiki?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20150925124536/https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can find the old wiki and excerpt text from SEDE. This [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/683803?tagname=crontab&opt.textResults=true) does that:

```
select '!!! ---- EXCERPT ---- !!!' as body
union all
select p.text -- markdown
from tags t
inner join posthistory p on p.postid=t.excerptpostid
where tagname = ##tagname:string##
and posthistorytypeid = 5
-- only most recent revision
and p.id = (select max(id) 
            from posthistory 
            where postid = p.postid and posthistorytypeid = 5 )
union all
select '!!! --- WIKI ---- !!!'
union all
select p.text -- Markdown
from tags t
inner join posthistory p on p.postid = t.wikipostid
where tagname = ##tagname:string##
and posthistorytypeid = 5
-- only most recent revision
and p.id = (select max(id) 
            from posthistory 
            where postid = p.postid and posthistorytypeid = 5 )
```

If you output this as a textresult you can easy copy/paste.

If you don't fancy SEDE you can use the [webarchive](https://web.archive.org/web/20150925124536/https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info) as shown by [Hans](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350576/is-it-possible-to-restore-wiki-of-tag-aliased-to-another-tag/350579#comment481164_350576)

Comment: Neat. BTW, result is returned as HTML. Does that mean the content has been in HTML or the query automatically converted wiki markup to HTML?

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski that was slightly complexer but I changed the query to return the latest markdown instead of the html.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the cron wiki accordingly and it waits for review. As I am satisfied with the answer, shall I vote to close my question?

Comment: @ArturR.Czechowski No, the question is fine, it can stay open. No need to close it,  it is helpful for future visitors